# Getting an error when using Synaptic Package Manager, unmet dependencies

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, upgrade, dependencies

I'm running ubuntu 18.04. When I tried to update using synaptic package manager I got the following message

```
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

So then I went online looking for a solution and tried a whole bunch of stuff. Here's what I've been able to gather so far. All of this is stuff I tried after reading other posts, so I'm not sure how relevant any of it is, but I thought I'd include as much information as I have.

When I do `sudo apt-get update` it works just fine. When I do `sudo apt-get upgrade` I get the following message.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libegl-mesa0 libegl-mesa0:i386 libgbm1 libgbm1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri
  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libglapi-mesa libglapi-mesa:i386 libglx-mesa0
  libglx-mesa0:i386 libosmesa6 libosmesa6:i386 libxatracker2 mesa-va-drivers
  mesa-va-drivers:i386 mesa-vdpau-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers
  mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386 netplan.io
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
```

When I do `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` I get the follwing message.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Error!
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gvfs : Depends: gvfs-daemons (>= 1.36.1-0ubuntu1.3.3)
        Depends: gvfs-daemons (< 1.36.1-0ubuntu1.3.3.1~)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

When I do `sudo apt-get install -f` I get the following message.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
```

So, I think I have unmet dependencies, but I have no clue how to fix that or if that even is the problem. If anybody can help me, I would appreciate it very much.

### Update

Don't know what happened, but after a while everything started working again. Synaptic started working again, however a new location on the File Manager appeared called x-nautilus-desktop:///. When I click on it, it says it can't be displayed. Weird stuff.

Comment: Looks like you recently tried to install some wrong-version or non-Ubuntu package, usually from a PPA or other non-Ubuntu source. Do you recall doing so recently?

Comment: not really, the last thing I installed was master pdf editor, but that wasn't a new program. I already had it on my computer it was just a re-install, and it works just fine.

Comment: Sometimes the installed software works; sometimes not. Where did you get it from? And exactly which release of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: i got it from code-industry.net/masterpdfeditor. I'm running 18.04. I honestly don't think that this piece of software is the problem.

Comment: I agree with you - that deb's control file has nothing that would cause held packages. Search your memory farther back.

Comment: I'm not sure. This isn't something I've ever had before. Do you think the gvfs package has something to do with it? I'm not sure what that is but it does say that it has unmet dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Then remove the package which appears in the output by running this command

```
sudo dpkg --remove package-name
```

Comment: When I type that into the console nothing happens. It doesn't give any output

Comment: So I think the problem is coming from a third party repository ppa. If you add one, try to disable it then run update and upgrade commands again.